# How to add a new Android API/SDK to IntelliJ project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

How do I add a new Android API to my IntelliJ project? I'm trying to add 20 and 21 to my Android project. In the Project Structure view, when I select SDKs in the leftmost list view, I see API 7 - 19 along with the JDK.  When I use the plus (+) button, it allows me to scroll to the place where the SDK Manager apparently downloaded the latests SDKs, and I can browse and find (under the sources folder) android-20 and android-21 folders right along with all the others.  But when I select one of them and then click the "Choose" button, nothing gets added.  Inconceivable.  Here's what my Project Structure view looks like:

[image]

And below is a pic of the contents of my Android SDK folder, although apparently the SDK Manager downloads specific API SDKs into the sources folder. In it I have SDKs 7 - 21 now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not select the subfolders, but rather the top-level SDK folder. Once you do this a dialog will be displayed showing all detected versions in that SDK structure, which you can then select to add.

Comment: @freedom, Would you mind being specific?  Notice the folders that are displayed in the pic.  I tried the "sources" folder, which contains all the SDKs, but that didn't work.  The SDK Manager is definitely putting things into my /Applications/android-sdk-macosx folder, but which specific one should I be using? (I'll add a another helpful pic)

Comment: @freedom,  I tried with the top-level folder (android-sdk-macosx), to no avail.  Just does nothing.  The form closes when I click "Choose", but nothing changes.

Comment: The `android-sdk-macosx` is the correct folder to choose. The fact that it does nothing probably means that you have some issue with your IntelliJ installation or perhaps your JDK is outdated. It might be best if you (reset your IntelliJ configuration)[http://www.lahiru.org/2012/01/how-to-reset-intellij-idea-settings-in.html] - just backup the settings first in case you need to undo.

Comment: For the record, I did not arrive at a solution. I moved the project to Android Studio.  I think @freedom is correct in that IntelliJ is somehow messed up (its installation) and that his answer is the correct one.  Cannot confirm though.